# moving files from an unknown folder to other

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am extracting .tar.gz files which inside there are folders (with files with many extensions). I want to move all the .txt files of the folders to another, but I don't know the folders' name.

.txt files location ---> `my_path/extracted/?unknown_name_folder?/file.txt`

I want to do --->  `my_path/extracted/file.txt`

My code:

```
os.mkdir('extracted')
t = tarfile.open('xxx.tar.gz', 'r')
for member in t.getmembers():
      if ".txt" in member.name:
            t.extract(member, 'extracted')
      ###
```

Comment: @Noxeus I want to move all the files that ends with '.txt' and move it to extracted folder,

Comment: If you run your code, what happens? I'm looking at your code but can't figure out why that wouldn't work.

Comment: @Noxeus for example, inside 'xxx.tar.gz' there is an unique folder ('folder'), inside folder 'folder' there are files like: image.jpg, text.txt,text2.txt...  If I run the code, I get my_path/extracted/folder/, and inside: text.txt,text2.txt

Comment: Have you tried `t.extract(member, os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'extracted'))` ? I'm just guessing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try extracting the tar file first ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163668/how-do-i-extract-a-tar-file-using-python-2-4))

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("xxx.tar.gz")
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

and then use the `os.walk()` method ([See here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm))

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.\\xxx\\'):
    txt_files = [path for path in files if path[:-4] == '.txt']
```

OR use the glob package to gather the txt files as suggested by @alper in the comments below:

```
txt_files = glob.glob('./**/*.txt', recursive=True)
```

This is untested, but should get you pretty close

And obviously move them once you get the list of text files

```
new_path = ".\\extracted\\"
for path in txt_files:
    name = path[path.rfind('\\'):]
    os.rename(path, new_path + name)
```

Comment: You can also `glob.glob('./**/*.txt', recursive=True)` to get all the paths to files matching the pattern.

Comment: Thats pretty cool. I knew about the glob package, but never thought to use it recursively